# Replacing a character in a string in assembly MASM

Tags: string, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

**What have I done before**

I was trying to simply replace or overwrite a character in a particular location in a string. I wrote this code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myMessage BYTE 'This is a string',0


.code
main PROC
call Clrscr  
mov esi, OFFSET myMessage
inc esi
inc esi
inc esi
mov ebx, 'a'
mov [esi], ebx
mov  edx, OFFSET myMessage
call WriteString
call crlf

exit
main ENDP

END main
```

**The problem**

The expected output of this program is "Thia is a string"
but it outputs "Thia".
Now wherever I overwrite a character in a particular location in this string, when I print it using a call to WriteString, the printing of that string stops at the location wherever the byte is replaced.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Hint: how big is `ebx`?

Comment: .. and how are 4 bytes going to hold a single character 'a'? (You *are* getting there.)

Comment: yes! it works with bl. 
mov [esi], bl
and that works. thanks :)
+1